# How is music preference related to personality traits or particular qualities?

Tags: personality, music

I'm a big music enthusiast myself, and one thing I noticed about myself, and not exactly about other people, is that I don't have any music genre I prefer listening to. For example, I don't mind it being rock, rap, techno or any music genre for that matter. As long as the beat is catchy, the quality of execution is there, and I can enjoy listening to it, I'll do so.

Hence, I've been wondering if there is any correlation between people liking certain kinds of genres and having certain qualities, skills or personality traits? For example, are people who like certain genres more creative or outgoing?

Comment: I've been hoping this question would come up :) Welcome to cogsci.SE!

Comment: Whoever answers this, please add opinions about heavy metal, hard rock and symphonic metal.

Answer (score 4):

As your luck would have it, there is [a study by Schwartz et al. (2003) that examines just that](http://dx.doi.org/10.1023/A:1022547520656).

They found that there was a specific personality type associated with music preference in adolescents. The paper [is freely available on familywise.ca](http://familywise.ca/documents/MusicPreferencesPersonalityStyle.pdf).

<sub>Schwartz, K. D., & Fouts, G. T. (2003). [Music preferences, personality style, and developmental issues of adolescents.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1023/A:1022547520656) Journal of youth and adolescence, 32(3), 205-213. [(PDF)](http://familywise.ca/documents/MusicPreferencesPersonalityStyle.pdf)</sub>

Comment: It looks like a good starting point; hopefully either the author of this answer or someone else can edit this answer to incorporate something of what was found in the article to make this self-contained.